# How to decode longest sub-bytes into str?

Tags: python, string, decode

Suppose I read a long `bytes` object from somewhere, knowing it is `utf-8` encoded. But the read may not fully consume the available content so that the last character in the stream may be incomplete. Calling `bytes.decode()` on this object may result in a decode error. But what really fails is only the last few bytes. Is there a function that works in this case, returning the longest decoded string and the remaining bytes?

`utf-8` encodes a character into at most 4 bytes, so trying to decode truncated bytes should work, but a vast majority of computation will be wasted, and I don't really like this solution.

To give a simple but concrete example:

```
>>> b0 = b'\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3'
>>> b1 = b'\x9c\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x9c'
>>> (b0 + b1).decode()
>>> 'ÄÖÜÄÖÜ'
```

`(b0 + b1).decode()` is fine, but `b0.decode()` will raise. The solution should be able to decode `b0` for as much as possible and return the bytes that cannot be decoded.

Comment: @usr2564301 That's true. UTF-8 is self synchronizing. So I can check each byte backwards discarding non-first bytes. All right. But the question still has its value when you don't know about the encoding of the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing the basic usage of [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper): a buffered text stream over a binary stream.

```
>>> import io 
>>> txt = 'before\N{PILE OF POO}after' 
>>> b = io.BytesIO(txt.encode('utf-8'))
>>> t = io.TextIOWrapper(b) 
>>> t.read(5) 
'befor'
>>> t.read(1) 
'e'
>>> t.read(1)
''
>>> t.read(1) 
'a'
```

Contrast with reading a bytes stream directly, where it would be possible to read halfway through an encoded pile of poo:

```
>>> b.seek(0) 
0
>>> b.read(5)
b'befor'
>>> b.read(1)
b'e'
>>> b.read(1)
b'\xf0'
>>> b.read(1)
b'\x9f'
>>> b.read(1)
b'\x92'
>>> b.read(1)
b'\xa9'
>>> b.read(1)
b'a'
```

Specify `encoding="utf-8"` if you want to be explicit. The default encoding, i.e. `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)`, would usually be utf-8 anyway.

Comment: Sir/Madam, after consuming all decodeable bytes with `TextIOWrapper`, how do I get the remaining bytes? Furthermore, doc says it is [slow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#id3) and [opaque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell).

Comment: I'm possibly reinventing wheels and I'm wondering if that's worthwhile... I really want to only keep one copy of binary data and decode when needed, and that reconstruction thing feared me: Is it reconstructing bytes from chars? That would be encoding not decoding.

Comment: The title Sir/Madam is inappropriate, henceforth please address as **"Your Royal Badgerness"**.  If the stream is not complete, you should wait for more bytes, either blocking (sync) or yielding (async), leaving some bytes buffered if necessary.

Comment: Badgerness: Couldn't `codecs.iterdecode()` be used somehow to do this?

Comment: @martineau Looks good. The incremental decoder has a `getstate()` method whose return value includes undecoded input.

Comment: I've never used it, but if it helps by all means edit directly into answer. What is the use-case for accessing undecoded input, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Cyker: If you edit your question and add some code illustrating the problem with an actual test data, I'll see if I can come up with a formal answer based on using `codecs.iterdecode()`.

Comment: @martineau OK I updated the question with a simple example with which `codecs.iterdecode()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments under @wim's answer, I think you could use the [`codecs.iterdecode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.iterdecode) incremental decoder to do this. Since it's a generator function, there's no need to manually save and restore its state between iterative calls to it.

Here's how how it might be used to handle a situation like the one you described:

```
import codecs
from random import randint


def reader(sequence):
    """ Yield random length chunks of sequence until exhausted. """

    plural = lambda word, n, ending='s': (word+ending) if n > 1 else word

    i = 0
    while i < len(sequence):
        size = randint(1, 4)
        chunk = sequence[i: i+size]

        hexrepr = '0x' + ''.join('%02X' % b for b in chunk)
        print('read {} {}: {}'.format(size, plural('byte', len(chunk)), hexrepr))

        yield chunk
        i += size


bytes_obj = b'\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x9c\xc3\x84\xc3\x96\xc3\x9c'  # 'ÄÖÜÄÖÜ'

for decoded in codecs.iterdecode(reader(bytes_obj), 'utf-8'):
    print(decoded)
```

Sample output:

```
read 3 bytes: 0xC384C3
Ä
read 1 byte: 0x96
Ö
read 1 byte: 0xC3
read 3 bytes: 0x9CC384
ÜÄ
read 2 bytes: 0xC396
Ö
read 4 bytes: 0xC39C
Ü
```